# "Message reply took too long." - Watch Connectivity Issues with Watch OS 3

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-3, watchconnectivity

In my project, I use `Watch Connectivity` to send messages to and from the Watch and iPhone. I can send a message to the phone and receive an array of strings when launching the app, however when using actions I get the following error;

> Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7012 "Message reply took too long."

Here's how things are set up;

First, the watch sends a message to the phone and then the phone sends an array of strings to display in a `WKInterfaceTable`. This sometimes works when loading the app. ( I fetch all NSManagedObjects called `Items` and use their `title` string properties to store in an `array` called `watchItems`.

However, I have an action on the watch to delete all items in the array and refresh the table with the new data.

The action on the watch uses a `sendMessage` function to send the `item` to the phone to delete from the array, then the phone sends the newly updated array to the watch and the watch updates the table. However, I either get the same array back or an error.

Pretty simple right, so everything actually worked fine before Swift 3 and Watch OS3/iOS 10; the entire app used to work.

Here's how I have everything set up;

**Phone App Delegate**

```
import WatchConnectivity

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {

var session : WCSession!

var items = [Items]()

func loadData() {
    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Items>(entityName: "Items")

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "remove == 0", "remove")

    do {
        try
            self.items = moc!.fetch(request)
        // success ...
    } catch {
        // failure
        print("Fetch failed")
    }
}

//WATCH EXTENSION FUNCTIONS
//IOS 9.3 
/** Called when the session has completed activation. If session state is WCSessionActivationStateNotActivated there will be an error with more details. */


//HAVE TO INCLUDE
@available(iOS 9.3, *)
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?){
   print("iPhone WCSession activation did complete")
}


@available(iOS 9.3, *)
func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {}

func sessionWatchStateDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {

}

//APP DELEGATE FUNCTIONS

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    //Check if session is supported and Activate
    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self;
        session.activate()
    }
    return true
}


}

//DID RECIEVE MESSAGE
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Swift.Void) {


    loadData()

    func loadItems() {
        watchItems.removeAll()

        for a in self.items {
            watchItems.append(a.title)
        }
    }

    var watchItems = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

    let value = message["Value"] as? String

    //This is called when user loads app, and takes some time when using refresh action, sometimes times out 

    if value == "HELLOiPhone/+@=" {

        print("Hello Message Recieved")

        loadItems() 

        //send a reply
        replyHandler( [ "Items" : Items ] )

    }

    //Not sure if receiving but does not delete array and send back to watch
    if value == "removeALL@+=-/" {                        
        for index in self.items {
            index.remove = 1
            //Saves MOC
        }

        loadData()
        loadTasksData()

        //send a reply
        replyHandler( [ "Items" : Items ] )

    }
    else {
        for index in self.items {
            if index.title == value {
            index.remove = 1
            //Saves MOC
            }
        }

        loadData()
        loadTasksData()

        //send a reply
        replyHandler( [ "Items" : Items ] )
    }
}
```

**WATCH**

```
import WatchConnectivity

class SimplelistInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate  {


/** Called when the session has completed activation. If session state is WCSessionActivationStateNotActivated there will be an error with more details. */
@available(watchOS 2.2, *)
public func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {

   //Fetch data is a function which sends a "HELLOiPhone/+@=" message to receive the array and displays in the table. This works 
   fetchData()
}


var session : WCSession!
var items = ["Refresh Items"]

override func didAppear() {
    fetchData()
}

override func willActivate() {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    super.willActivate()
    //Check if session is supported and Activate
    if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
        session = WCSession.default()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
    fetchData()
}

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    fetchData()
}

@IBAction func refresh() {
    print("Refresh")
    //Works but sometimes message is delayed
    fetchData()
}

@IBAction func removeAll() {
    print("Remove All Items is called")
    if WCSession.default().isReachable {
        let messageToSend = ["Value":"removeALL@+=-/"]
        print("\(messageToSend)")
        session.sendMessage(messageToSend, replyHandler: { replyMessage in
            if let value = replyMessage["Items"] {
                self.items = value as! [String]

                Not receiving message
                print("Did Recieve Message, items = \(self.items)")
            }

            }, errorHandler: {error in
                // catch any errors here
                print(error)
        })
    }
    fetchData()
}

}
```

Comment: The `WCSession` APIs only takes dictionaries with property list types, but I see you are sending `Items`. What are these objects, and are you sure they are supported by the WCSession APIs?

Comment: @ccjensen Items is actually a `NSManagedObject` however I fetch them and use their title properties which are of string value to create an array, before sending to the watch. However for each fetch on the watch, the phone is supposed to update the data and refetch. This isn't happening and often get the error.

Comment: Also the watch actually does just fine when displaying the data, however when trying to removing the object is does not respond.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should not send or receive custom class objects from one target(iOS) to second target(watchOS) instead you should send/receive data in dictionary format such as [String: Any] and this dictionary should contain array of your custom objects required properties in key value pair in simple dictionary. This could easily be decodable at watch side.
2. You should make a decoupled class extending WCSessionDelegate such as below so that this class could be used not only in ExtensionDelegate but also in any WKInterfaceController.

   ```
   class WatchSessionManager: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

       static let sharedManager = WatchSessionManager()

       private override init() {
           super.init()
           self.startSession()
       }

       private let session: WCSession = WCSession.default

       func startSession() {
           session.delegate = self
           session.activate()
       }

       func tryWatchSendMessage(message: [String: Any], completion: (([String: Any]) -> Void)? = nil) {
           print("tryWatch \(message)")
           weak var weakSelf = self
           if #available(iOS 9.3, *) {
               if weakSelf?.session.activationState == .activated {
                   if weakSelf?.session.isReachable == true {
                       weakSelf?.session.sendMessage(message,
                                                     replyHandler: { [weak self]  ( response )  in
                                                       guard let slf = self else {return}
                                                       //Get the objects from response dictionary
                                                       completion?(response)
                           },
                                                     errorHandler: { [weak self] ( error )  in
                                                       guard let slf = self else {return}
                                                       print ( "Error sending message: % @ " ,  error )
                                                       // If the message failed to send, queue it up for future transfer
                                                       slf.session.transferUserInfo(message)
                       })
                   } else {
                       self.session.transferUserInfo(message)
                   }
               }else{
                   self.session.activate()
                   self.session.transferUserInfo(message)
               }
           } else {
               // Fallback on earlier versions
               if self.session.activationState == .activated {
                   if self.session.isReachable == true {
                       self.session.sendMessage(message,
                                                replyHandler: {  ( response )  in
                                                   //Get the objects from response dictionary
                                                   completion?(response)
                       },
                                                errorHandler: {  ( error )  in
                                                   print ( "Error sending message: % @ " ,  error )
                                                   // If the message failed to send, queue it up for future transfer
                                                   self.session.transferUserInfo(message)
                       })
                   } else {
                       self.session.transferUserInfo(message)
                   }
               }else{
                   self.session.activate()
                   self.session.transferUserInfo(message)
               }
           }
       }


   }
   ```

Now you could easily send a message to your iOS app to wake up and get data from there (e.g from CoreData) using the above function in any WKInterfaceController and the completion block will have your required data such as

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["request": "FirstLoad"]
WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.tryWatchSendMessage(message: dict,completion:{ (data) in print(data)})
```

Same way you should use this WatchSessionManager on iOS side and receive the request and as per the requested key you should take data from core storage/db and send list of custom objects in simple key-value Dictionary pattern within replyHandler of didreceiveMessage function such as below.

```
 func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String: Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String: Any]) -> Void) {
 var dict: [String: Any] = [String: Any]()
 replyHandler(dict) //This dict will contain your resultant array to be sent to watchApp.
}
```

Some time iOS App(Killed state) is not reachable to WatchApp, for solving that problem you should call "tryWatchSendMessage" within Timer of around 3 sec interval. And when you get connection from watchApp then you should invalidate the timer.

The sendMessage functionality of WatchConnectivity is so powerful to wake your app up. You should use it in optimized manner.

Answer (score 0):

I have just dealt with my WatchOS app. And there was a situation when I received "Message reply took too long".

Then I added background task handler to my iOS app and started to send messages every second to WatchOS app. The message contained `UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining`. So i get: 45sec, 44sec, ..., 6sec, 5sec, ... If the timer runs below 5 sec no messages will be delivered to/from iOS app and we will get "Message reply took too long". The easiest solution was to send blank messages from watch to phone each time the timer goes below 15 sec. The `backgroundTimeRemaining` will be updated to 45 seconds again: 45, 44, 43, ..., 17, 16, 15, (blank message), 45, 44, 43, ...

Hope it helps someone