# How to fix Error: 7012 Message reply took too long - WCSession WatchOS 3

Tags: ios, watchos-3, wcsession

I have been trying stuff like this:
["Message reply took too long." - Watch Connectivity Issues with Watch OS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515619/message-reply-took-too-long-watch-connectivity-issues-with-watch-os-3)

as well as trying anything and everything I can find... but cannot find a mistake.

However I am still getting errors. I am using the simulator... is it even possible to test WCSession stuff with the simulators or can I only do this on devices?

Answer (score 1):

In the event that others come across it.

2 things I needed to do:

1. Make sure my ReplyHandlers were always being set
2. Reset Content and Settings on the simulators

Was able to get successful messages after that.